# alternative for "row_number() over(partition by"

Tags: sql-server

looking for alternative for query below
Without `row_number() over(partition by` :

```
select *,row_number() over(partition by [Tag Name],[PRD] order by [Start Time]) num
from [PRD Project].[Data].[efan1]
```

Comment: why you are looking for an alternative?

Comment: The application provider doesn't like it for some reason

Comment: lol... maybe he/she wish to downgrade to MS Access?

Comment: Its mssql server and using certain application provider

Comment: I know it is SQL server, I was being sarcastic because there's really no reason to not like it other than performance. Window functions are there for being used.

Comment: Can you provide input data?

Answer (score 0):

We can try creating tablevariable with identity column and insert selected data here to get row_number as output

```
declare @test table (i int identity(1,1), test varchar(10))
```

Comment: how is this related to the question?

Comment: Cant use table variable, looking for one query and something like with join or group by.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think `ROW_NUMBER` is probably the best way to do this, here's one alternative.

The setup:

```
 CREATE TABLE [#test] ([Col1] CHAR(1) -- This is what we're partitioning by
                     , [Col2] INT);   -- This is what we're ordering by

 INSERT INTO [#test]
 SELECT CHAR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%16+65) -- Random single letters A:P
      , ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000      -- Random numbers 1:1000
 FROM [sys].[objects];
```

The queries:

```
 -- Original ROW_NUMBER query
 SELECT *
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Col1] ORDER BY [Col2]) AS [RN]
 FROM [#test]
 ORDER BY [Col1]
        , [rn];


 -- Alternative w/ CROSS APPLY
 SELECT *
 FROM [#test] [t1]
      -- For each row in #test,
      -- Get the number of rows in #test where our partitioning column (Col1) is the same and the ordering column (Col2) is lower
      -- Add 1 to get the initial value to start at 1 instead of 0 (i.e. for the first value per partition, there are 0 rows with a lower ordering value)
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS [rn]
                   FROM [#test] [t2]
                   WHERE [t1].[Col1] = [t2].[Col1]
                         AND [t1].[Col2] > [t2].[Col2]) [t2]
 ORDER BY [Col1]
        , [rn];
```